# Right way to create a background job in an elixir phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
  def create(conn, %{"data" => %{"attributes" => user_params}}) do

    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        UserMailer.send_welcome_email(user)
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("show.json", model: user)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(MyApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

In this controller action, `UserMailer.send_welcome_email` is synchronous, and the request waits.

I wanted to make it asynchronous, so spawned a process like this instead

```
spawn_link(fn ->
  UserMailer.send_welcome_email(user)
end)
```

The request doesn't not wait until the mail has been sent.

- Though it works, is it the right way to do ?
- Are there any chances that these process become orphan or they just die after immediately executing?
- Should we create a `Supervisor` instead?
- Should we use a library like https://github.com/akira/exq instead? (I feel even if `spawn_link` fails, and logs it in our phoenix logs, it would do)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting a process using `spawn_link/1` will cause a bidirectional link, so whichever of the spawning process and the newly spawned process that happens to die first will kill the other one (unless it's trapping exits, which it probably shouldn't be). That's great in some cases, and not so great in others; if it takes a long time to send that e-mail, for example, the Phoenix request might finish first, and risk killing off the spawned process.

Due to the linking, however, there shouldn't be any risk of the processes getting orphaned.

A better approach is definitely to create a `Supervisor` (or using `Task.Supervisor`), and you could roll your own background job setup rather easily.

However, it might be worth looking at something like `exq` that you mentioned, or [Toniq](https://github.com/joakimk/toniq) for example, that could possibly have everything you need already; especially things like retries in case of failure, and presistence. There are also some other interesting options in the [Awesome Elixir](https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir) list if you want to try out a few different alternatives.

Comment: Btw, for a list with background queue options, you can check https://elixir.libhunt.com/categories/862-queue as well. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply use `spawn\3` and that'll do the job but the problem here is that, as it was mentioned by Johan, there won't be any retries or interface to track down jobs and so on so you're probably better off using an external library.